# .Net 6 core WebApi - Cancellation token property isCancellationRequested always false from API call

Tags: asp.net-web-api, axios, cancellation-token

It's my understanding that the isCancellationRequested property of the cancellation token should be true when passing in a token from the API call.
I'm not sure if my assumption is incorrect or if it's something in the implementation of the endpoint or API call?

Controller:
[image]

Axios POST request
[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the help centre.

Comment: _"It's my understanding that the isCancellationRequested property of the cancellation token should be `true` when passing in a token from the API call"_ - **no**, your understanding is incorrect. `IsCancellationRequested == true` only when the `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` method is invoked (which can be an explicit call, or a call after a timeout, or some other mechanism, e.g. ASP.NET will call `Cancel()` when the HTTP connection is closed when a request is still being processed).